# Multiple values for one <option>

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I'm trying to gain a better js-knowledge, and got a little problem.
I want to give a option more than one vaule, and from what i could find other places, arrays with split was the best solution. But I can't get it to work.
One side of the script is supposed to calculate a price, dependent on the selected destionation, while the other is the name on the destinaton.

```
<form name="ORDER" method="post" >
<select name="destination" id="destination_trV">
<OPTION VALUE="10,Cannes"> Cannes</option>
</form>
```

I want one part to grab the "10" to use this calculation purposes, and another to grab "Cannes" to write.

```
var dest_1 = (document.getElementById("destination_trV").value);
var vari_1 = dest_1.split(",",1);
var vari_2 = dest_1.split(",",1,2);
```

this is supposed to write out "10"

```
document.getElementById("linje5").innerHTML="Priceclass: " + vari_1 + "<br>";
```

this is supposed to write out "Cannes"

```
document.getElementById("linje6").innerHTML="Destination: " + vari_2 + "<br>";
```

But this doesn't work :)

Comment: use [`[data-*]` attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#data-0) rather than trying to perform crazy data parsing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite green at this, can you explain that a little closer :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would happen if one of those values were to contain a `,` character? You'd need some form of encoding to preserve the original data. Instead of trying to jam multiple values into a single attribute, you'd be better off splitting those values into separate [`[data-*]` attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#data-0):

```
...
<option value="Cannes" data-destination="Cannes" data-price-class="10">Cannes</option>
...
```

That way, when you want the values, you can select the element and get the attribute values separately:

```
(function () {
    var opt,
        destination,
        priceClass;
    opt = document.getElementById("destination_trV");
    destination = opt.getAttribute('data-destination');
    priceClass = opt.getAttribute('data-price-class');
    document.getElementById('linje5').innerHTML = 'Priceclass: ' + priceClass + '<br>';
    document.getElementById('linje6').innerHTML = 'Destination: ' + destination + '<br>';
}());
```

Comment: Yes, thats what i were looking for. Thank you :)!

Answer (score 1):

Split does not work that way [MDN split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
string.split([separator][, limit])
```

Just do the split once

```
var vals = dest_1.split(",");
var vari_1 = vals[0];
var vari_2 = vals[1];
```

A better way would be to use data attributes.

Comment: data-stedsnavn="Cannes", like this? and grab that with element.dataset.stedsnavn - in any way?